# C Getopts: Managing all received options and optional optargs

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, getopt

I am writing on a program that should get up to 3 options while they can be combined as well. The part look like in following:

```
char flag = 0; // to mark which options were set
int aopt = INT_MAX; // default to INT_MAX if no args delivered
char bemerkung[100];
memset(bemerkung, '\0', 100); // string to receive via '-b'

char option;

while((option = getopt (argc, argv, "m:a:b:")) != EOF){
    switch( option ){
        case 'm': {
            flag = flag | 1;
            break;
        } 
        case 'a': {
            flag = flag | 2;
            char * arg = optarg;
            aopt = atoi(arg);
            if(aopt == 0 && strcmp("0", arg) != 0) // if no valid optarg was entered
                aopt = INT_MAX; // get back the default value
            break;
        }
        case 'b': {
            flag = flag | 4;
            strcpy(bemerkung, optarg);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option entered.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

// some code here, not touching `flag`

if(flag == 1){
    // deal with `-m`, no optargs
}
if(flag == 2){
    // `-a aopt` called
}
if(flag == 3){
    // `-m -a aopt` called
}
```

The basic idea is to set the bits in `flag` such that I can handle the options and their combinations later. But the trouble I face right now is that `-m` requires arguments (should be optional for `-m` only) and `./main -m -a 0` results into `flag = 1` instead of `flag = 3`.

How do I make arguments for `-m` optional and get the `OR` to be done correctly for the `flag`?

Comment: Why does `m` take an argument at all if you're not doing anything with `optarg`?

Comment: `-m` does not require an argument, but acts as an option flag. The output will differ depending on which options or their combinations have been set (dealt later using `flag`), but I cut that part out since it is not necessary for this question.

Comment: So ... why are you telling `getopt` that `m` requires an argument? I'm confused.

Comment: Probably I am too noob to figure out how to tell getopt not to take an argument explicitly for `m` only. Was it done via `:`?

Comment: See [`man 3 getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html).

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was because of the colon as shown there. But the problem with the `OR` operation is still there, though...

Comment: You need to explain what the behaviour you want for each option, rather than show us the code that does not do that.

Comment: I just added the conditions showing how the `flag` is used. Showing everything however would be beyond what this platform is for as it is a few hundred lines of code. The `flag` however remains unchanged after checking the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `-m` to not take any arguments, then omit the `:` that follows it in the options string.  The `:` means that the preceding option expects an argument:

```
while((option = getopt (argc, argv, "ma:b:")) != EOF){
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the `optargs` problem. But the main problem with the `OR` seems a little tricky. I cannot find any way, how `flag = 1 | 2` would not result in `flag = 3`.

Comment: With the above fix, the value of `flag` is 3 after the loop for me.  Check your change and how you call the program.